# Trying to get an alert when I scroll the window using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script.js file that has these functions

```
$(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function (){
        alert('you just scrolled!');
    });
});

/* ================================
             Preloader
=================================*/

$(window).on('load', function () { //wait untill the website is fully loaded
    $('#status').fadeOut();
    $('#preloader').delay(350).fadeOut('slow');
});

$(function () {
    $('#s-stages').owlCarousel({
        items: 2,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplayHoverPause: true,
        smartSpeed: 700,
        loop: true,
        nav: true,
        dots: false,
    });
});

$(function(){
    $('#stages-tabs').responsiveTabs({
        animation:'slide'
    });
});
```

all of the above are working except

```
$(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function (){
        alert('you just scrolled!');
    });
});
```

the above function can work if it is in the index.html file

Comment: its working have you included jquery ?

Comment: yes and I have 2 other functions in the same file are working

Comment: Then pleas edit your question and add the whole code, due the fact that the code above is working

Comment: I have 2 functions on the same file are working, this function specifically is not working when it is in script.js but when I include it on the index file it works

Comment: then pleas edit your question and append the given file. It could be that the the part of the script never get reached

Comment: thanks I edited the question

Comment: @user159496 Your code appears to work fine. See [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ogv7wbh6/). Maybe you are not scrolling the window but an element inside it? We can't really help if we can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: thanks a lot, I am trying to know what is the problem as I know it should be working. it works fine when inserted in the body of the index.html

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to all replies. I found the solution. the javascript file wasn't refreshing any updates. the solution is to put ?view=3 in the 
and it will reflect any changes